# Visual Studio 2013 Installer Project - Error in 32 bit os

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation

I created an installer setup project in visual studio 2013 (using the new visual studio 2013 installer template - available from 04/2014) .

For 32 bit installs i set the Target Platform to x86.
Installation works fine on 64 bit machines but failed on 32 bit - both in winxp and server 2003.

I get an error dialog with the message: "The installer was interrupted before  could be installed. You need to restart the installer to try again."

In the installation log i found:
"Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038"

I tried opening and compiling the same solution with visual studio 2010. This time it worked.

The only difference i can think about is that vs 2013 setup project is using windows installer 4.5 (which i defined as a prerequisite) while vs 2010 is using installer 3.1.

Comment: Just curious are your using a certificate to sign your exe's?

Comment: No, i certificate is not used.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  I am having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26039835/2686738

This applies to Installer Projects created in VS2013 (via the extension) which are unable to install onto Windows Server 2003 or other x86 Windows OS.

Users may see the following errors:

"The installer was interrupted before could be installed. You need to restart the installer to try again"

"Windows cannot open this program because it has been prevented by a software restriction policy."

"Error 0x80070643"

"Event ID 1603"

I hope this helps more people find the answer to this problem.