# Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, installer projects extension

Tags: .net-3.5, windows-installer, failed-installation

Having upgraded from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 and installing the Visual Studio installer projects extension.
The Setup up project builds and the installer works in Windows 7 and Windows 8 but when trying to run it on Windows Server 2003 ( Standard Edition, Service pack 2)
it exits with Error 1603.

Microsoft’s Support site suggests:

- The folder that you are trying to install the Windows Installer package to is encrypted.
- The drive that contains the folder that you are trying to install the Windows Installer package to is accessed as a substitute drive.
- The SYSTEM account does not have Full Control permissions on the folder that you are trying to install the Windows Installer 
  package to. You notice the error message because the Windows Installer service uses the SYSTEM account to install software.

None of the above are causing the error, having gone back to VS2010 and built the project again it has installed with no problems.

The project is using the .NET 3.5 SP1 Framework and Windows Installer 3.1. The Windows Installer component couldn't be found and I had to copy it.

FROM: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages

TO: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages

Has anyone experienced any similar issues?

**Update 1**
Thanks @PhilDW

I have done the install creating a log file, I have copied the section I think is relevant but the full log can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kj2y7ftze2he6g8/Modus.log?dl=0).

```
Action 11:55:50: DIRCA_CheckFX. 
Action start 11:55:50: DIRCA_CheckFX.
MSI (c) (64:24) [11:55:50:139]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'DIRCA_CheckFX' 
MSI (c) (64:B0) [11:55:50:170]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1.000\LOCALS~1\Temp\1\MSI1D4.tmp, Entrypoint: CheckFX
MSI (c) (64:D4) [11:55:50:170]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (64:D4) [11:55:50:170]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (64:D4) [11:55:50:170]: Connected to service for CA interface.
Action ended 11:55:50: DIRCA_CheckFX. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (64:24) [11:55:50:217]: Doing action: FatalErrorForm
Action 11:55:50: FatalErrorForm. 
Action start 11:55:50: FatalErrorForm.
MSI (c) (64:24) [11:55:50:217]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'FatalErrorForm' 
MSI (c) (64:4C) [11:55:50:233]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
Info 2898. For VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
MSI (c) (64:4C) [11:55:50:233]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line1 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, Line1, to the right
```

I then found the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978677/dirca-checkfx-return-value-3-vs-2013-deployment-project) on here. The custom action is being added by Visual Studio is there anyway round this?

Comment: 1603 is a generic error, most commonly caused by a custom action crash. If you have any custom actions I'd look at them carefully, especially if they have dependencies that may not be on the target system. Do the install creating a log with msiexec /I <path to your msi> /l*v <path to a text log file> to see where it's failing.

Comment: I had the same problem and resolved the issue by following the steps posted by GhostCKY on SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978677/dirca-checkfx-return-value-3-vs-2013-deployment-project. I also tested the on Win7 with no issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem that I have Ally.  There is no documented workaround, other than to continue using 2010 to build your MSI.  GhostCKY has put a potential solution on my question regarding the "DPCA.dll" file from the 2010 solution, which I haven't tried yet but seems promising.

The error is very misleading, as it means that the DLL load failed.  the DIRCA_CHECKFX action is trying to load the DLL, so it gives you a horrible error.

The "right" way to fix this is WiX, but obviously budget comes into play.

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried copying the dll over and it worked. For anyone else having the same problem the solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978677/dirca-checkfx-return-value-3-vs-2013-deployment-project