# Cannot run the Setup file which created by VS2013 in windows xp

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-xp, setup-deployment

Created a Setup file developed in c# in VS-2013, Dotnet4 framework and for 32bit Architecture. It is getting installed in windows 7 and windows 8 but not in Windows XP (SP3) with administrator previllege. 
Error : "The installer was interrupted before application could be installed. You need to restart installer to try again." Help need in this regard.

```
Output of msiexec /i Setup.msi /l*v MyLogFile.txt

=== Verbose logging started: 2/12/2015  20:19:11  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 3.01.4001.5512  Calling process: C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:125]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:125]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:125]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: Setup.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:125]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:234]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'D:\Setup.msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:234]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DigitalSignature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:234]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: D:\Setup.msi is not digitally signed
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:234]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: D:\Setup.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:562]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:562]: Attempting to enable all disabled priveleges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:593]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:593]: Original package ==> D:\Setup.msi
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:593]: Package we're running from ==> C:\DOCUME~1\admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\486c8b74.msi
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:593]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{DC3A4FA7-B437-455E-ABE4-13FA61195AF2}'.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:593]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:609]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 0
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: User policy value 'TransformsAtSource' is 0
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiFileHash 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{DC3A4FA7-B437-455E-ABE4-13FA61195AF2}'.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Transforms are not secure.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Command Line: CURRENTDIRECTORY=D:\ CLIENTUILEVEL=0 CLIENTPROCESSID=3796 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackageCode property. Its value is '{80AB49AE-1D7B-4E2B-83B4-ED5310D6B599}'.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Product Code passed to Engine.Initialize:           ''
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Product Code from property table before transforms: '{DC3A4FA7-B437-455E-ABE4-13FA61195AF2}'
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Product Code from property table after transforms:  '{DC3A4FA7-B437-455E-ABE4-13FA61195AF2}'
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ProductState property. Its value is '-1'.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Adding new sources is allowed.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackagecodeChanging property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Package name extracted from package path: 'Setup.msi'
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Package to be registered: 'Setup.msi'
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:640]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:656]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:656]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:656]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:656]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:656]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:656]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:671]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:671]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:671]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:671]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:671]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:671]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 0
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: Running product '{DC3A4FA7-B437-455E-ABE4-13FA61195AF2}' with user privileges: It's not assigned.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CURRENTDIRECTORY property. Its value is 'D:\'.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTUILEVEL property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTPROCESSID property. Its value is '3796'.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: TRANSFORMS property is now: 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionDatabase property. Its value is '200'.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Application Data
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Favorites
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\admin\NetHood
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\admin\PrintHood
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Recent
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\admin\SendTo
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Templates
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Local Settings\Application Data
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\My Pictures
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Start Menu
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\Fonts
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:687]: Note: 1: 2898 2: MS Sans Serif 3: MS Sans Serif 4: 0 5: 16 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:718]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:718]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:718]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding USERNAME property. Its value is 'MACET'.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:718]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:718]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding COMPANYNAME property. Its value is 'Marthandam College of Engineering and Technology'.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:718]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASE property. Its value is 'C:\DOCUME~1\admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\486c8b74.msi'.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:718]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OriginalDatabase property. Its value is 'D:\Setup.msi'.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:718]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourceDir property. Its value is 'D:\'.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:718]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SOURCEDIR property. Its value is 'D:\'.
MSI (c) (D4:7C) [20:19:11:718]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionHandler property. Its value is '3.01'.
=== Logging started: 2/12/2015  20:19:11 ===
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:734]: Note: 1: 2262 2: PatchPackage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:734]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:734]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:734]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UILevel property. Its value is '5'.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:734]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:734]: Doing action: INSTALL
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:734]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ActionText 3: -2147287038 
Action 20:19:11: INSTALL. 
Action start 20:19:11: INSTALL.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:734]: UI Sequence table 'InstallUISequence' is present and populated.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:734]: Running UISequence
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:734]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding EXECUTEACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:11:734]: Doing action: DIRCA_CheckFX
Action 20:19:11: DIRCA_CheckFX. 
Action start 20:19:11: DIRCA_CheckFX.
MSI (c) (D4:A4) [20:19:11:796]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\DOCUME~1\admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\MSI161.tmp, Entrypoint: CheckFX
MSI (c) (D4:54) [20:19:11:812]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (D4:54) [20:19:11:812]: Attempting to enable all disabled priveleges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (D4:54) [20:19:11:812]: Connected to service for CA interface.
Action ended 20:19:12: DIRCA_CheckFX. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (D4:B4) [20:19:12:218]: Doing action: FatalErrorForm
Action 20:19:12: FatalErrorForm. 
Action start 20:19:12: FatalErrorForm.
```

ACUBE.

Comment: Have in mind that both win7 and win 8 have .NET 4 pre-installed, something which is not valid for win XP. if your seup file does not specify to install .NET you may have issues

Comment: But i have already installed .NET4 in windows xp

Comment: There's a similar error message in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26039835/4551527). The accepted answer says to copy over a dll from a VS 2010 install.

Comment: Setup file created by vs2013 always checks for dot net 4.5 before installing, even though i changed the project solution to dot net 4 before creating the setup file.

Comment: I have your question. Did you find any answer for that?

Comment: no i didnt find the answer for this, instead i switched from vs 2013 to vs2008 and i didnt face any problem

Comment: which Windows  Installer Version ("Schema" ) is selected in setup project ?

Answer (score 13):

I'll attempt to document the basic problem.  At issue is a DLL that gets embedded in the MSI that provides custom actions that the installer uses, like the `CheckFx()` function that fails here.  A helper function that checks the installed .NET Framework version.  You'll find it back on your machine in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VSI\bin\dpca.dll.

Core problem is that this DLL is no longer compatible with XP.  VS2012 was the first VS version that started changing the minimum required Windows version for executables.  Something you can see by running `Dumpbin.exe /headers dpca.dll` from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.  The output, trimmed to fit:

```
Dump of file dpca.dll

PE signature found

File Type: DLL

...

OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
             10B magic # (PE32)
           12.00 linker version
           34200 size of code
            8800 size of initialized data
               0 size of uninitialized data
           133E3 entry point (100133E3)
            1000 base of code
           36000 base of data
        10000000 image base (10000000 to 1003FFFF)
            1000 section alignment
             200 file alignment
            6.00 operating system version              // <=== here
           10.00 image version
            6.00 subsystem version                     // <=== here
               0 Win32 version
        ... etc
```

Note the marked version numbers, 6.00 is the Windows version of Vista.  XP belongs to the previous generation, major version 5.  Inevitably the custom action fails, the DLL cannot be loaded on XP.

Working around this problem is technically possible, you need to replace dpca.dll with an older version, one that can still work on XP.  You need access to an earlier version of VS, 2010 or less.  The topic of [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978677/dirca-checkfx-return-value-3-vs-2013-deployment-project).

Otherwise yet another reminder that XP truly is over and done with.  Pass the support cost on to your clients and they tend to start doing the right thing :)  Can't help with that however.

Answer (score 0):

I was using **Visual Studio Installer** From Microsoft, after googling around with no answers I decided to try out **InstallShield Limited Edition** from Flexera Software. This successfully installed on my Windows XP machine.