# How to create a windows Xp installer via Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wix, windows-xp

I have a windows Application developed in Visual Studio 2013.

When i tried to install the current installation on Windows XP, i get an error as "The setup file was interrupted. Appname could not be installed.Please try again"

After i did some google, i found that build files of Studio 2013 is not supported for Windows XP.

I need help for creating the required setup file for Windows XP OS via VS 2013?

Comment: Do you have the latest .NET Framework installed on Windows XP? Wix expects at least 4.0 to be present if I remember correctly...

Comment: Try running your MSI from the command line with verbose logging. This should help you identify what the problem is. msiexec /i <your file name> /L*v

Comment: The failure is typically in the CheckFX call that looks for the .NET FW. If you can avoid that it might work. Also keep in mind that the the issue is not as narrow as you say - XP itself is not supported, so nothing you build today is supporrted on XP.

Comment: @jesse : I have installed the latest .Net Framework but still no help

Comment: @PhilDw: I need for testing in one of the systems. How can i avoid that ChechFX Call?

Comment: Ok, sorry, I meant to say: Open the MSI file with Orca, find DIRCA_CheckFX in the InstallExecuteSequence and the InstallUISequence and delete them (or set the condition to be False) and see if that gets you past the error.

Comment: See: [DIRCA_CheckFX Return Value 3 VS 2013 Deployment project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978677/dirca-checkfx-return-value-3-vs-2013-deployment-project)