# visual studio 2013 installer for windows xp

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, windows-xp

My sw is developed under VisualStudio 2013 on Windows7.
I need it to work on a Windows XP with .NET 3.5 sp1 installed and it works well under XP. All the projects target only .NET 3.5.

Now I'd like to create an installer, so I downloaded the setup project extensions and created it. 
But it did not work on XP until I found the workaround in [DIRCA_CHECKFX Return Value 3 - VS 2013 Deployment Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978677/dirca-checkfx-return-value-3-vs-2013-deployment-project) 
.

But now when it install it asks me to install .NET 4.5 too, and I can't download additional packages.
I have disabled all prerequisites from the properties of the setup project and the libraries and executables only need .NET 3.5 that is already installed, but it keep me asking again .NET 4.5. Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems your code is for .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the prerequisites there is also a check in the launch conditions of the actual setup project, in View->Editor->Launch conditions.